# LSTM Prediction on Sub-Sequences Fail

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a simple dataset, something like:

```
data = [
        [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]],
        [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60], [70, 80], [90, 100]],
        [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8], [0.9, 0.10]],
        [[0.01, 0.02], [0.03, 0.04], [0.05, 0.06], [0.07, 0.08], [0.09, 0.010]],
        [[11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18], [19, 20]]
       ]
```

where each input is *quite different* from the other.

Each input corresponds to a different class:

```
classes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

I am training LSTM as follows:

```
# Build Model
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=units, activation='tanh',
               batch_input_shape=(1, None, n_features),
               dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout,
               return_sequences=return_sequences, stateful=stateful))

model.add(Dropout(dropout_))
  
self.model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train
model.fit(x=np.array(data), y=np.array(classes), batch_size=1)
```

I could achieve 100% accuracy on the training set. However, if I try to predict it on ***sub-sequence*** it fails tremendously to know to which class the sub-sequence belongs to! Such as:

```
[[1,2], [3,4]]
[[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]]
[[0.01, 0.02], [0.03, 0.04]]
[[11, 12], [13, 14]]
```

Applying different parameters for the above: `units`, `dropout` ...etc. To fix overfitting (if any), did not work.

---

**Summary:**

**Prediction on sub-sequences never exceeded 60% accuracy regardless of number of epochs trained, parameters tuning and different optimizers and learning rates used..etc!**

I want to move from this to a bigger dataset, but I am unable to make this work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first split your dataset into train and validation (develop) datasets. Maybe with a test split as well. Then measure the performance on the validation dataset.

You could also augment your dataset with the sub-sequence examples and train/validate on those.

Comment: Thanks and plus one. I already tried with validation test before writing the question and it's the same.. Never exceeds 60% as I mentioned previously. I'm basically asking the question here as a last chance before augmenting it as it'll take forever to finish training with big dataset and it'll be spoon fed

Comment: you could augment and train for less epochs then

Comment: Exactly and with proper dropout to avoid extreme overfitting. But can u confirm that LSTM isn't ***automatically*** able to predict on sub sequence without this workaround?

Comment: Maybe you actually need a max or mean before the dense classification layer. Using max/mean over time steps in LSTM is a common approach for classification

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and back to ya. In the mean time please edit ur question and add simple example of ur suggestion.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. No max or average pooling layer improved the prediction on the cv, on contrary it made it even worse!

Comment: Also tried to augment it with a lot of sub-sequences, the improvement was very little and when I tried on a bigger dataset, it failed to exceed 50% accuracy on CV!

Comment: I don't have currently further suggestions. You can add those things you tried to your question and hopefully someone might have other suggestions!